Spring Boot App throwing a strange exception
I am following a tutorial and everything seems to work for the author but not for me.
The purpose of the use case is to add a new category (id, name, image and a boolean value).

Category entity:
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private Boolean isActive;
}

Here my controller:
@PostMapping("/admin/category/add")
public String saveCategory(@ModelAttribute Category category, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file,
        HttpSession session) throws IOException {

    String imageName = file != null ? file.getOriginalFilename() : "default.jpg";
    category.setImage(imageName);

    Boolean existCategory = categoryService.existCategory(category.getName());

    if (existCategory) {
        session.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Category Name already exists");
    } else {

        Category saveCategory = categoryService.save(category);

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(saveCategory)) {
            session.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Not saved ! internal server error");
        } else {

            File saveFile = new ClassPathResource("static/img").getFile();

            Path path = Paths.get(saveFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "category_img" + File.separator
                    + file.getOriginalFilename());

            // System.out.println(path);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            session.setAttribute("succMsg", "Saved successfully");
        }
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/category";
}

And here the view:
<form action="/admin/category/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Enter Category</label> <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Status</label>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" checked
                                            value="true" name="isActive" id="flexRadioDefault1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                            Active </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="isActive"
                                            value="false" id="flexRadioDefault2"> <label
                                            class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                                            Inactive </label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label>Upload Image</label> <input type="file" name="image"
                                        class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-12 mt-2">Save</button>
                            </form>

I am receiving the following exception:
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

Validation failed for object='category'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.sap.Shopping.Cart.controller.AdminController.saveCategory(com.sap.Shopping.Cart.model.Category,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws java.io.IOException: [Field error in object 'category' on field 'image': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@73eb957e]; codes [typeMismatch.category.image,typeMismatch.image,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [category.image,image]; arguments []; default message [image]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:224)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
As the error is saying, there is type mismatch issue for the image, but I couldn't figure out what to change exactly.

Your image isn't a String but a binary representation of your image wrapped in a MultipartFile. Create a dedicated form objct to operate with your controller which takes a MultipartFile for the image. Then store the image somewhere and convert that form object to your actual entity and fill the image String with whatever you need it to be (probably the actual location).

Your Category object contains an image field that conflicts with the form's multipart image parameter. Change the field name in the Category object to imageName to resolve the issue.

this leads to the same exception...

By the way, in the tutorial he is using @RequestParam as well and it works fine.

@Gothiquo Can you show the full stack trace of the error?

@Gothiquo Your Category object contains an image field that conflicts with the form's multipart image parameter. Change the field name in the Category object to imageName to resolve the issue.

yes sure, I updated the question.
